# What is the Environmental variable for this path d:\a\r1\a in VSTS Relase definition?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have build and release definitions.I am publishing some ps1 files to release definitions to run at the time of release definition.So In the scripts I am using this path:**d:\a\r1\a** but I don't want to use this path instead wan to call using relative path.How to call this with Environmental variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When vsts runs build it Release tasks, it also provides environment variables to help you determine the context. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables) for those variables.

The agent's working directory can be accessed as `$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)`. Within a script running on the agent, the same information is available as an environment variable. It can be referenced within a PowerShell script as `$ENV:AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY`.

Ex: `Get-ChildItem -Path $ENV:AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY`

Comment: I don't find the relative path for d:\a\r1\a in your link.Please help me out.

Comment: Apparently given the path you are mentioning you're working on releases at the moment. Here is the link to the documentation for the environment variables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch

Comment: Shall I use this C:\agent_work\r1\a in my script instead of giving d:\a\r1\a.So that if any upgradation/changing of URL's/Path's in VSTS in future no builds/release definitions are going to beaffected and It will work fine.Please just confirm.

Comment: Don't use a hard coded path. Leverage The environment variable that will always contain the right path instead.

Comment: ,That's what please share me the environmental variable for this path  d:\a\r1\a.I am new to VSTS that's why asking your help.

Comment: Again your question is not precise enough to know which one you need, this is why I'm pointing you to the documentation that lists all of them.

Comment: @ baywet,My question is simple.I want to call this path d:\a\r1\a with an environmental variable.how to call this path ?Please help me out.

Comment: I am guessing that you want to access the artifacts download folder. This is provided by the variable Agent.ReleaseDirectory which is exposed via the environment variable $Env:AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY again, all of that is in the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See I want to call this path with environmental variable. This is the line in my Powershell Script.[object]$paramObj=Get-Content "d:\a\r1\a\Jobs\WebJobs_scripts\WebJob_list.json" |ConvertFrom-Json. So Shall I call this line as : [object]$paramObj=Get-Content "AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY \Jobs\WebJobs_scripts\WebJob_list.json" |ConvertFrom-Json. Please confirm me.

Comment: @baywet I updated your answer a bit to include the information in the link provided. I also changed the link to point to the Release environment variables instead of the Build environment variables.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks! we went on a bit of a discussion here :)

Comment: @DanielMann, Its failing with the below error when I run this path $Env:AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY ----->Error:2018-06-11T07:02:21.7089777Z ##[command]. 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\3d9d583b-76c3-40db-a365-5e664c2eabda.ps1' 
2018-06-11T07:02:23.7078662Z ##[error]At C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\3d9d583b-76c3-40db-a365-5e664c2eabda.ps1:2 char:24. Please help me.

Comment: The question "what's the variable for" has been answered. I suggest you post a separate question with the script you're trying to have working, the folder structure and some other details.